# get custom date time format

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to display date time as eg. Dec 1, 09 11:22:45 PM using SQL query

Currently my format is :

```
 DATENAME(Month, (((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+ 621355968000000000) -599266080000000000) / 864000000000) + SPACE(1) + DATENAME(d, (((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+ 621355968000000000) - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000) +', ' + DATENAME(year, (((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+621355968000000000) - 599266080000000000) /864000000000) + SPACE(1)+DATENAME (hour,(((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+621355968000000000) - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000) + ':' +DATENAME (minute,(((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+ 621355968000000000) - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000) + ':' +DATENAME (second,(((MachineGroups.TimeAdded*10000000)+ 621355968000000000) - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000) AS Expr2
```

Ussing the above i get eg. December 1, 2009 23:22:45

I tries using the cuatom formata of "MMM" and "yy" but it did not work

any suggestions???
thanks

Is there no way i can use the Datename property above to get my desired format??

Comment: In what way are ASP.NET and C# relevant to this question? It sounds like you're only interested in the SQL side. On the other hand, is there any reason why you want SQL to do the formatting rather than doing it in your ASP.NET code?

Comment: this is because i have already done the above formatting at many places... and now it is just needed to modify it a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier and more efficient to return the value as a generic datetime object and format it in your UI.

What is your motivation for returning a formatted date from the database?

Comment: i have already done the above formatting at many places... and now it is just needed to modify it a little bit more... thanks though

Answer (score 0):

This will get you everything but AM/PM:

declare @myDate datetime
set @myDate = getdate()
select LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @myDate),3) + ' ' + 
        RIGHT('0'+DATENAME(DD, @myDate),2) + ', ' +
        RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @myDate),2) + ' ' +
        convert(varchar,(DATEPART(hour, @myDate))) + ':' + convert(varchar,(DATEPART(minute, @myDate))) + ':' + convert(varchar,(DATEPART(second, @myDate)))

There are various ways to achieve the AM/PM values, among them would be a substring of:

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109)

Answer (score 0):

As well as MONTHNAME (which you're already using), check out DATEPART. It's also not far from the CONVERT format of 9 [via `CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @datetime, 9)`], so you could manipulate this as well.

Yet another option is using two CONVERTs ... this gives you what you want, but the time's in 24hr format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @datetime, 107) + ' ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @datetime, 108)
```

Use a different conversion function and a bit of string manipulation to get you 12 hour with AM/PM. Or do something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(hh, @datetime) - 12 AS VARCHAR)
        + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(mi, @datetime) AS VARCHAR) 
        + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(ss, @datetime) AS VARCHAR) 
        + CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, @datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 11 THEN ' AM' ELSE ' PM' END
```

Neither this or manipulating the output of CONVERT is pretty, but they're your best options.

***HOWEVER:*** as others have pointed out though, this is normally better done client/UI-side rather than SQL-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all supported SQL Server [formats here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx).

To select in a format equivalent to `Dec 1, 09 11:22:45 PM`, you could use the date from format 7: `Mon dd, yy`.  The time can be assembled from format 109: `mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)`.  Combined:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 7) + 
    ' ' +
    stuff(
        substring(
            convert(varchar(32), getdate(), 109)
        ,13,14) -- Substring HH:mi:ss.mmmAM
    ,9,4,' ') -- Replace .mmm by one space
```

This should print:

```
Nov 24, 09  4:58:36 PM
```

The second of the two spaces between `09` and `4` is reserved for a two-number hour, like 11:59:59 PM. :)

Comment: @unknown: I guess You could.  But the query with convert is simpler, so why would you?